# How to allow FireFox and Chrome to display a jpg

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4, firefox, jpeg

I am using IE 8, 9 and 10 as well as the most recent versions of FireFox and Chrome.  I use GhostScript to convert a PDF to JPG.  This works fine and it stores the JPG in the same location as the PDF.  I have checked rights on this folder and everything is correct.

IE, even old IE8, will display the JPG in a jQuery QTip pop-up window.  I am returning the JPG from an MVC controller to a partial view.  This works very well in IE 8 and 9.  In current versions of Chrome, FireFox, and even recent Safari, this does not work.

My partial view simple contains the following.

```
@model System.String
<img src="@Url.Content(@Model)" alt="" style="width:480px;height:520px"/>
```

and the string passed in is of the format

```
\\servername\location\jpgfile.jpg
```

Again, this works in IE 8+ but not in FireFox and Chrome.  Since this is running on the SAME server from where the PDF and JPG are, I tried this with no success either, which would have been a correct reference also but fails for all browsers.

```
d:\location\jpgfile.jpg
```

The odd thing is that the Developer Tools for Chrome reveals that

```
\\servername\location\jpgfile.jpg
```

resolves to

```
file://servername/location/jpgfile.jpg
```

and I can cut and paste this into the URL and it will open just fine.

Anyone dealt with this before?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the action control, called from the ajax request, should return a File result gotten from a stream.